# How to Integrate Barcode Scanner into Java Inventory Management Program

Tags: java, barcode, inventory-management

This is the First time am using a handheld bar code scanner in any application. The barcode scanner is Zebex Z-3110 Handeld Bar Code Scanner. i want to use this bar code scanner to scan bar codes on item which will then read the code feed it to Java Inventory management program that am working on, then the Java program will use the code fed to it by the Bar code scanner to search the database for details of that item. the barcode scanner will also be used to read the item barcode when it's been recorded to the inventory. urgent help needed.

Comment: Can you specify the problem you are having? Nobody knows your Inventory Management System and it is hard to guess what problems you are running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as if there is another keyboard attached that enters the numbers of the barcode. You just have to assure that the right input field of your program is selected.

You might want to take a look at the [Programming Guide](http://www.zebex.com/Product/documunts/Z-3110/Z-31xx_ProgrammingGuide.pdf) of the scanner on the [Zebex Z-3110 Website](http://www.zebex.com/Product/Handheld/Z-3110.html).

Comment: The documentation link is broken.

Comment: years   later,   am  back   just   to  thannk you,   thats   what   solved  it for   me.